# Unexpected directory layout after running make

Tags: go, makefile, serverless

I was following [serverless golang lambda support](https://serverless.com/blog/framework-example-golang-lambda-support/), but when I got to step

```
$ cd myservice
$ make
```

I got this error:

```
dep ensure
env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/hello hello/main.go
unexpected directory layout:
    import path: github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda
    root: /home/yasmine/go/src
    dir: /home/yasmine/go/src/myservice/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda
    expand root: /home/yasmine/go/src
    expand dir: /home/yasmine/go/src/myservice/vendor/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda
    separator: /
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Probably your GOPATH is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've tried building before, nothing went wrong. My GOPATH is `home\yasmine\go`.

Comment: @nabski Maybe your GOPATH is indeed the problem. On Unix you should use forward slashes, as in `GOPATH=/home/yasmine/go` (note in the output it says: `separator: /`.

Comment: @Jens sorry I mistyped, it is in `/home/yasmine/go`.

Comment: @nabski: I've got the same issue, any solution ?